# counting the number of solutions

Tags: combinatorics

Let $p$ be a prime number. Count the number of solutions $A$ in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb Z_p)$ to the equation $\det(A) = 0$.

Attempt of solution:
$\mathbb Z_p = \{0,1,2,...p-1\}$

I tried listing down the elements of $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb Z_p)$ and check which ones have $\det = 0$
But now I am stuck
I would appreciate if anyone could guide me

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have any results from which you can start? Is this really from  combinatorics class?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to count the matrices with determinant $\ne 0$, and then subtract this from the total number $p^{n^2}$ of matrices.

We now proceed to count the matrices with non-zero determinant. 
So we want the rows to be linearly independent.

The first row can be any of the $p^n-1$ non-zero vectors.

For each choice of first row, only the $p$ multiples of that row are forbidden. That leaves $p^n-p$ choices. So the first two rows can be chosen in $(p^n-1)(p^n-p)$ ways.

The first two rows are linearly independent. For any choice of first two rows, only the linear combinations of these are forbidden for the third row. These linear combinations are all distinct, so there are $p^2$ of them, leaving $p^n-p^2$ choices.

So there are $(p^n-1)(p^n-p)(p^n-p^2)$ ways to choose the first three rows so that they will be linearly independent.

Continue.